# Force a UITextView to redisplay after changing contentInset?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I change the contentInset.  How can I force it to update the display to reflect the new value?

Comment: What happens right now? Changing the contentInset should in general be enough.

Comment: Current behavior is unpredictable.  But it does not reliably update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that it did update the contentInset immediately, but it didn't look like it because it adjusts the location that the UITextView is scrolled to such that the display of the UITextView doesn't change.

By scrolling back to the top-left corner, it has the effect I think you're looking for of updating the display with the new content inset:

```
[textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Interesting.  I found this to work in a simple test environment with a single UIViewController, and just a UITextView. I updated the contentInset on a button press, and then made the above call to scrollRectToVisible.  Can you reproduce your issue in a simple test environment?  Otherwise, maybe there's some other context affecting the behavior that could be useful to solving your issue.

Comment: Interesting, your solution does appear to work in the simple test.  I'll have to do some more testing to see what is going on.

Comment: Any luck figuring out what the difference between the simple test and your application was?

Comment: I got engaged in a different direction.  Anyhow, you answered the question as stated, so congrats.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue if not the same issue.

I was able to get setNeedsDisplay to work, but you have to use it and place it on the right view and call it in the right order or it won't work.

I have a view that I want to reuse, all I change is a UITextView and an image on the view depending on where it is opened from. I have the label accessible via Outlet on the controller. I could tell that my assignment was working as the changed value would show up the 2nd time I went back to the modified view. I could not get any of the previously suggested ways to work until I hooked up setNeedsDisplay on the controllers view (NOT the UITextView, as I tried that and it did not take) and I had to do it just before I make the text change as it did not work if I made the call after the setText. Anyway, maybe setting it up in this way and in that order may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[textView setNeedsDisplay]`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is to re-init it with the new properties.  Sounds like a waste, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now.  But as you say, it seems wasteful, and I want a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `[textView layoutIfNeeded]` or `[textView layoutSubviews]`.

I take it back, the documentation of this method suggests that:

> The default implementation of this
>   method does nothing.

and

> You should not call this method
>   directly.

Answer (score 0):

Does [textView setNeedsLayout] do it?